# Websocket handshake response not forwarded from TCP to client

Tags: networking, google-chrome, tcp, wireshark

I am trying to create a websocket server. I can see the websocket client's opening handhshake. My response to it is received by the client laptop (I can see this on wireshark). So the TCP connection has been established. But the client (a chrome websocket client extension) does not receive the handshake packet. What could be a possible reason for TCP to not forward the handshake to the client or for the client to not be able to read the TCP message?

Client handshake:

```
GET HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection:Upgrade
Cache-Control:no-cache
Host:192.168.0.101
Origin:http://www.websocket.org
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key: qrmw/m+BoZije6h9HYKmVw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
```

Server Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: jj1g5Io57m9ks8cme3jkbyo2asc=
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.websocket.org
Server: xyz
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the WebSockets spec, a blank `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header is not allowed and considered malformed data, and "the recipient of such malformed data MUST immediately *Fail the WebSocket Connection*." (emphasis theirs)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-9.1

If your WebSockets server doesn't support any of those extensions, you should omit that header rather than appending it but leaving it malformed (blank). Elsewhere in the spec it mentions that the client should consider the support extensions list to be null if that header was not present in the server's response.

**Updated to add:**
I also believe your server's `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` output is incorrect.

I wrote the following shell function to take a `Sec-WebSocket-Key` value and calculate a `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` from it

```
wscalc () {
    WSGUID="258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    echo -n "${1}${WSGUID}" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
}
```

I tested this with the example from the WebSockets specification [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3) and it gets the value correct:

```
$ wscalc dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

But when I run it on your client's `Sec-WebSocket-Key`, I get a different value from what your server put in its `Sec-WebSocket-Accept`:

```
$ wscalc 'qrmw/m+BoZije6h9HYKmVw=='
B18B9fmlWz7D6Gu9eCWRNkcB1II=
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't seem to make a difference. The problem is that TCP is not forwarding the packet to webscoket. What could be the possible reasons for this? I have checked the TCP port for websocket on client side. It matches the destination TCP port in the server packet.

Comment: @Saharsh Are you using the Javascript WebSockets API on your client? If so, are you saying your onmessage event handler isn't getting called? Do you have an onerror event handler? Is it getting called?

Also, I've updated my Answer to highlight another error I think your WebSockets server is making.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I got it to work. You're right. The problem was in the SHA-1. Thanks for your help :)